# haml Ruby on Rails, add link into table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, link-to

I'm trying to add a link into my table, group.link holds a URL and I want to make this into a clickable link. This is what I've tried to do so far but it isn't correct:

```
- @groups.each do |group|
  %tr
    %td= group.name
    %td= group.description
    %td= #{link_to group.link}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
- @groups.each do |group|
  %tr
    %td= group.name
    %td= group.description
    %td= link_to "Click", group.link
```

Comment: Sure thing! Consider "selecting/checking" the answer to mark it *closed*.